# Find the matrix of the transformation with respect to the bases of V.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the sets $Y = \{1, x, x^2\}$ and $X = \{1, 1 + x, 1 + x + x^2\}$ be bases of $V$.

Let $D: \ V \to V$ be defined such that $D(f)$ is the derivative of $f$, for any $f {\in}  V$. Find the matrix of $D$ with respect to the bases $Y$ and $X$.

I know the answer but I am not quite sure how to get there.

Answer:$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & -2\\ 0 & 0 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Are you sure the answer is correct? I think $a_{1,3}=-1$

Comment: This was the solution posted by my professor. I think it is correct but I have no way of confirming.

Comment: Oh, I did it the other way around. Posting an answer now.

Comment: Would you know how to do this sort of problem if you have vectors of numbers instead of polynomials?

Comment: @amd I believe so, couldn't I just follow a similar route to the one that Itay4 gave me in the answers?

Comment: The reason I asked is that you wrote that you weren’t sure of how to get to the answer. One way to do so is to convert the problem to one that you *do* know how to solve by replacing the polynomials with elements of $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to check how the linear transformation "acts" on the elements of $Y$, and then represent them with respect to $X$:

$D(1)=0=0\cdot 1+0\cdot (1+x)+0\cdot (1+x+x^2)$

$D(x)=1=1\cdot 1+0\cdot (1+x)+0\cdot (1+x+x^2)$

$D(x^2)=2x=-2\cdot 1+2\cdot (1+x)+0\cdot (1+x+x^2)$

Placing the coordinates in columns of a matrix and we get the result.

Answer (score 1):

$D(x)=1$

Now  $a.1+b(1+x)+c(1+x+x^2)=1$

Implies that $a=1,b=0,c=0$

Also $D(x^2)= 2x$

Now $a.1+b(1+x)+c(1+x+x^2)=2x$

Implies $a+b+c=0,b+c=2,c=0$

Implies $a=-2,B=2,c=0$

Similarly for $D(1)$

Put them in columns nd get the required matrix